# FullTrustProcessLauncher in IBackgroundTask not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am trying to launch a `FullTrustProcess` from my Background task. For this I am calling `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();`, but it tells me `FullTrustProcessLauncher does not exist in this context`. I have tried adding `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP` and `Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract` references to my Background task, but then I am not able to compile it for release (Unless I disable .Net native toolchain). The error I then get is: `Internal compiler error: An item with the same key has already been added.`

How can I fix this? My background task needs to somehow launch the WPF component. Is there a workaround, like launching a UWP foreground app without a window? Or do I have an import/permission wrong? Note that I only seem to need to add one of the references, but with both it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this as reference to the project that implements the background task:
[image]

Then you will find the FullTrustProcessLauncher APIs in the Windows.ApplicationModel namespace. Also make sure the component is a "Windows Runtime Component", not a "Class Library". If this doesn't work, please share a repro project that demonstrates the problem. It has worked for me in my projects.

Comment: Note: I still got the error at first, I had to comment out FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(); everywhere, rebuild and then add it back again for it to work.

Comment: Comment out, rebuild, uncomment, rebuild doesn't work for me.

Comment: I tried using a C# runtime directive rather than doing this in the class, but that also can't find the file when my app starts.